Is the WHEN NOT MATCHED part of PostgreSQL's MERGE statement thread-safe?
I would like to use PostgreSQL's merge (since version 15) to perform a "insert if not exist" query. Something like the following:
MERGE INTO borrowed_books AS bb
USING (VALUES
    (101, 'user123', '2024-12-01')  -- book_id, user_id, due_date
) AS source(book_id, user_id, due_date)
ON bb.book_id = source.book_id AND bb.user_id = source.user_id
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (book_id, user_id, due_date)
    VALUES (source.book_id, source.user_id, source.due_date)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET due_date = source.due_date
RETURNING *;


Is the WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN clause free of race conditions in concurrent writes? Specifically, will this query prevent other concurrent transactions from inserting rows with the same book_id and user_id that would violate the WHEN NOT MATCHED condition before the insert occurs? Assuming there is no unique constraint on book_id and user_id.

Note sure for postgresql, but I know for SQL Server I tend to avoid MERGE entirely, in part because it's definitely not atomic there.

From  MERGE: When MERGE is run concurrently with other commands that modify the target table, the usual transaction isolation rules apply; see Section 13.2 for an explanation on the behavior at each isolation level. You may also wish to consider using INSERT ... ON CONFLICT as an alternative statement which offers the ability to run an UPDATE if a concurrent INSERT occurs. There are a variety of differences and restrictions between the two statement types and they are not interchangeable.

No, and there's no such mechanism in any of the DML statements. My understanding is you're wondering whether this part:
ON bb.book_id = source.book_id AND bb.user_id = source.user_id

...has a chance of temporarily doing the job of a thread-safe constraint. Unfortunately, it works in isolation from all other transactions/workers/threads and that condition is not communicated to anyone else, regardless of you isolation level - all it does is direct the flow in this query between MATCHED and NOT MATCHED blocks, internally.
MERGE is using that to perform a join and based on the output of that, it'll switch between the actions you specify.
You can use advisory locks if you want some sort of custom, abstract type of locking things that may not even exist yet, on the fly, without prior DDL. Or you need prior DDL to define a constraint that a concurrent worker would violate if they tried to insert the same thing as you.
The older upsert method using insert..on conflict do update mentioned in the quote posted by @Adrian Klaver requires an arbiter index/constraint (constraints are enforced by indexes in Postgres). If you have that, or you can add that, it's that index that'll make either form of this upsert thread-safe - at most one non-violating row will be allowed to pass.
